# Creating a new column that devides dataset into quarters in R

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal weight dataset.I have created a column that has the starting date per ID for 12 months. I want to create another column that is called 'Quarters' where the data points, per each ID, will be categorized into Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 based on their starting date.

```
   dat_subf= dat_subf %>%
  mutate(
    Quarter= case_when (
      start <= start+as.period(12, unit='weeks')~'Q1',
      start >= start+as.period(13, unit='weeks')& start <= start+as.period(24, unit='weeks')~'Q2',
      start >= start+as.period(25, unit='weeks')& start <= start+as.period(36, unit='weeks')~'Q3',
      start >= start+as,period(37, unit='weeks')~'Q4'
    )
  )
```

I expect the final output to look like this.

```
|ID|weight|date|start|quarter|
|--|------|----|-----|-------|
|1| 120|2/4/2020|1/1/2020|Q1|
|1|121|5/2/2020|1/1/2020|Q2|
|2|100|1/17/2020|1/1/2020|Q1|
2|99|8/20/2020|1/1/2020|Q2|
```

*It's important to note that the starting date might differ between participants.
The code that have here is not working properly. I either get all the values for the column to read as Q1 or NA. I am not able to get all the categories as specified in the code.

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample input that illustrate the problem - `dput()` is the nicest way to share sample input because it is copy/pasteable and includes all the class information.

Comment: From your final output, it looks like your `date` and `start` columns are encoded as character strings, not `Date` class - that would be the first thing to look at. I also don't get your logic, `start <= start + ...` will always be true if what you are adding is positive. Should one of those be `date`, not `start`? Maybe `date <= start + ...`?

Comment: It seems that `cut` or `findInterval` would work well here.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do here:

1. Convert your dates to proper `Date` class (simple), then
2. use `cut` to use breakpoints and assign a quarter.

```r
quux[c("date","start")] <- lapply(quux[c("date","start")], as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
quux
#   ID weight       date      start quarter
# 1  1    120 2020-02-04 2020-01-01      Q1
# 2  1    121 2020-05-02 2020-01-01      Q2
# 3  2    100 2020-01-17 2020-01-01      Q1
# 4  2     99 2020-08-20 2020-01-01      Q2
```

Note that this is how R prints dates, period. If you later want to render into a table or plot and go back to your `m/d/Y` format, you'll need to convert back into a string to do that ... but most "math-like" operations with dates *break* with that type of strings.

From here, let's assign a quarter. This works,

```r
zoo::as.yearqtr(quux$start)
# [1] "2020 Q1" "2020 Q1" "2020 Q1" "2020 Q1"
sub(".* ", "", zoo::as.yearqtr(quux$start))
# [1] "Q1" "Q1" "Q1" "Q1"
quux$Quarters <- sub(".* ", "", zoo::as.yearqtr(quux$start))
quux
#   ID weight       date      start quarter Quarters
# 1  1    120 2020-02-04 2020-01-01      Q1       Q1
# 2  1    121 2020-05-02 2020-01-01      Q2       Q1
# 3  2    100 2020-01-17 2020-01-01      Q1       Q1
# 4  2     99 2020-08-20 2020-01-01      Q2       Q1
```

Your expected output looks like you are basing the quarter on `date` instead of `start`, easy enough:

```r
sub(".* ", "", zoo::as.yearqtr(quux$date))
# [1] "Q1" "Q2" "Q1" "Q3"
```